# Unable to find Qt5Core.dll при выполнении exe-шника на другом ПК без установленного Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Есть скрипт приложение калькулятора на Python с использованием PyQt5. Скомпилировал в .exe с помощью pyinstaller с опцией --onefile.
В итоге в папке dist появляется исполняемый файл, который у меня запускается, но при запуске на других компах без Python, он пишет что не может найти Qt5Core.dll в PATH. 
Но ведь я и собираю ексешник чтобы запускать на компах без питона и его библиотек.

Получается, для запуска приложения нужно предустанавливать Python на комп (тогда смысл собирать ексешник?), или я допускаю какие то ошибки при компиляции?

Лог компиляции:

```
pyinstaller -F calc.py
69 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
69 INFO: Python: 3.7.0
69 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
70 INFO: wrote C:\Users\m.karaganov\Documents\GitHub\Python-projects\calc.spec
72 INFO: UPX is not available.
77 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\m.karaganov\\Documents\\GitHub\\Python-projects',
 'C:\\Users\\m.karaganov\\Documents\\GitHub\\Python-projects']
78 INFO: checking Analysis
78 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
78 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
81 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
83 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3196 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
3198 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\python3\python.exe
5377 INFO: Caching module hooks...
5384 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\m.karaganov\Documents\GitHub\Python-projects\calc.py
5424 INFO: Loading module hooks...
5425 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
5525 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
5526 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
5662 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
5662 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
8564 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
8798 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
9856 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
11550 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
11550 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
11554 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
11558 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
30992 INFO: Looking for eggs
30992 INFO: Using Python library c:\python3\python37.dll
30993 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
31003 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\m.karaganov\Documents\GitHub\Python-projects\build\calc\warn-calc.txt
31043 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\m.karaganov\Documents\GitHub\Python-projects\build\calc\xref-calc.html
31051 INFO: checking PYZ
31052 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
31052 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\m.karaganov\Documents\GitHub\Python-projects\build\calc\PYZ-00.pyz
31596 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\m.karaganov\Documents\GitHub\Python-projects\build\calc\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
31609 INFO: checking PKG
31609 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
31610 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
31806 WARNING: One binary added with two internal names.
31806 WARNING: ('libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\python3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
31807 WARNING: was placed previously at
31808 WARNING: ('PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\python3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
40113 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
40117 INFO: Bootloader c:\python3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\run.exe
40117 INFO: checking EXE
40117 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
40118 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
40119 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\m.karaganov\Documents\GitHub\Python-projects\dist\calc.exe
40217 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Проверил линковку DependencyWalkerom. 
Не находит следующих DLL:

```js
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APIQUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COMM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L2-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CONSOLE-L3-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-CRT-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DATETIME-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DATETIME-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DEBUG-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DELAYLOAD-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-DELAYLOAD-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FIBERS-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-FILE-L2-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-HEAP-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-IO-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-IO-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-JOB-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LARGEINTEGER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LIBRARYLOADER-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MISC-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMEDPIPE-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMEDPIPE-L1-2-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NAMESPACE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-NORMALIZATION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PERFCOUNTERS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSENVIRONMENT-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSSNAPSHOT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTOPOLOGY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSAPI-ANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PSAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REALTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SIDEBYSIDE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYNCH-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-2-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSINFO-L1-2-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSTEMTOPOLOGY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-SYSTEMTOPOLOGY-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-LEGACY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-THREADPOOL-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINDOWSERRORREPORTING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINDOWSERRORREPORTING-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINDOWSERRORREPORTING-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WOW64-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WOW64-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-XSTATE-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CONSUMER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CONSUMER-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CONTROLLER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-PROVIDER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-APPCONTAINER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-AUDIT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-AUDIT-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-BASE-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-CORE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-CORE-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-CORE-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-MANAGEMENT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-MANAGEMENT-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-4.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-WINSVC-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-INTERNAL-L1-1-2.DLL
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPINIT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-ATOMS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALIZATION-OBSOLETE-L1-2-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-LOCALREGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-MEMORY-L1-1-3.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRINGANSI-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSION-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-VERSION-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DEVICES-CONFIG-L1-1-1.DLL
API-MS-WIN-DEVICES-QUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-CLASSICPROVIDER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-EVENTING-OBSOLETE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-UAP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-POWER-BASE-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-POWER-SETTING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CREDENTIALS-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CREDENTIALS-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-GROUPPOLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSALOOKUP-L2-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-LSAPOLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-PROVIDER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SECURITY-SDDL-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-STATESEPARATION-HELPERS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-ONECORE-APPMODEL-STATEREPOSITORY-INTERNAL-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-NPUSERNAME-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-NTMARTA-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-REGISTRY-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-ADVAPI32-SAFER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-APPEXECUTIONALIAS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-APPEXECUTIONALIAS-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-DAXCORE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPXDEPLOYMENTCLIENT-APPXDEPLOY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-APPXDEPLOYMENTCLIENT-APPXDEPLOYONECORE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-AUTHZ-CONTEXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-REMOTE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-EDPUTIL-POLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-EVENTING-RUNDOWN-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-FECLIENT-ENCRYPTEDFILE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-CLIPPING-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DC-CREATE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DC-L1-2-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DC-L1-2-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DRAW-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DRAW-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DRAW-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-DRAW-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-FONT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-FONT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-FONT-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-FONT-L1-1-3.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-DESKTOP-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-DESKTOP-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-INTERNAL-DESKTOP-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-METAFILE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-METAFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-METAFILE-L1-1-2.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-PATH-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-PRINT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-PRIVATE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GDI-WCS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-GPAPI-GROUPPOLICY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-DATETIME-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-ERRORHANDLING-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-FILE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-QUIRKS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-QUIRKS-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-REGISTRY-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNEL32-SIDEBYSIDE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-KERNELBASE-PROCESSTHREAD-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-MRMCORER-RESMANAGER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NETWORKING-WCMAPI-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTDSAPI-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTDSAPI-ACTIVEDIRECTORYCLIENT-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-MESSAGE-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-SYNCH-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-WINDOW-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-PROFILE-EXTENDER-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RPC-SSL-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-SYSPARAMS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-RTCORE-NTUSER-WINDOW-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CAPAUTHZ-L1-1-1.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-CHAMBERS-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SECURITY-EFSWRT-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-SHELL32-SHELLCOM-L1-1-0.DLL
EXT-MS-WIN-WINRT-DEVICE-ACCESS-L1-1-0.DLL
```

Прописывание пути к содержащим DLL (API-MS-WIN-...) директориям в PATH не помогли, так же как и копирование содержимого папки в директорию со скриптом. А вот EXT-MS-WIN-... вообще нет на компе. Что можно сделать?

Comment: Соберите так `pyinstaller calc.py` и посмотрите если ли в `dist` `Qt5Core.dll`, да и другие Qt'шные dll. У меня подобная фигня была с dll для opencv решил проблему ручным указанием dll в батник: `pyinstaller main.py --add-binary="<папка питона>\Lib\site-packages\cv2\opencv_ffmpeg345_64.dll;."`. А так, у меня там тоже pyqt5 используется и проблемы с захватом qt'шных dll не было

Comment: Собрал, в dist есть все что нужно, в том числе и Qt5Core

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте линковку всех DLL через https://stackoverflow.com/a/1993677/2101808 . Скорее всего нехватает `msvc` или `mingw` с которым собиралось `Qt`.

UPD:
Возможно Qt была собранна под десятку ли восьмерку, а запускаешь на семерке.

UPD:
Хотя скорее всего Qt 64битная, а pyinstaller 32-битный экзешник сделлал.

Comment: Проверил. Не находит следующие DLL:

Comment: комментарий обрезался.

или подкидывай их в папку с проектом или проси пользователя установить

Comment: Дополнил в шапку.

Comment: @MikeK это системные вызовы винды http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/apisetschema/api/index.htm?tx=4

Comment: @MikeK добавил пару вариантов ещё.

Comment: Да, .exe 32-х битный

Comment: питон и кутэ 32битные?

Comment: Питон тоже, QT через pip ставил, так что думаю что тоже 32, но явно это нигде не нашел.

Comment: @MikeK пробуй собрать все на семерке